# How to find closed questions for which I also voted to close?

Tags: support, search, closed-questions

Is there any way to find closed questions for which I also voted to close?

I would like to review my close votes in the past, just to get an insight whether other people picked the same closing reason and/or provided the comments for closing/improving the question, so that I can improve my decisions/actions in the future when it comes to unclear/too broad/etc questions.

I did not find any mechanism for such kind of search in the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: You can look at the [close votes tab of your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4754790/dragan-bozanovic?tab=votes&sort=closure). It's not great (it's not search), and it shows all your close votes, even if it didn't get closed, but still. If you know SQL, try [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to directly query the SO database, maybe someone has already written a query for this.

Comment: @JonasCz Yes, I'm blind, close votes tab is actually quite good for the that purpose. Regardless of this, I wasn't aware of the SEDE etiher, good to know. I suggest you write the comment as an answer, so that other people can find these information easier. Thanks!

Comment: I have a userscript that shows the consensus between your action and that of the community in the close vote history [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history/251508#251508)